# How do I to fix aspect ratio and apply coord_flip in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to produce the following chart in ggplot2 but I require it to be a horizontal plot rather than vertical. I also require the plot to be thin.

```
ggplot(Compositiondata, aes(x=1, y=`Composition`, fill=`Elements`),labels = FALSE) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(col.axis = "white",labels=FALSE)) 
+ ggtitle("Title") 
+ theme(axis.line=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        panel.background=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(),  
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),                                                            
        plot.background=element_blank()) 
 + coord_fixed(ratio = 0.05) +coord_flip()
```

When I apply `coord_flip()` the plot returns to its original width.
How can I flip the plot and retain a small width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reproducible data, my best guess would be to pass `aspect.ratio` through the `theme` not in `coord_fixed(ratio=0.05)`

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. The aspect.ratio of the theme refers to that of the panel, while coord_fixed() refers to the aspect ratio of the data.